# Combination optimization

Tags: algorithm, optimization, set, combinations, computer-science

I am creating an app that generates combinations of items which collectively satisfy a criteria supplied by the user. The following are the some details of the system;

1. There is a collection of gear which are categorized into 3 types.
2. Each gear has two abilities which are never the same.
3. A kit is a grouping of 3 different types of gear.
4. A kit may/may not have repeated <strike>attributes</strike> abilities.

The app allows the user to supply k abilities (0 < k < 7) and then generates all possible kits that have the specified abilities. (If k<6 then the kit may have  repeated abilities or unspecified abilities to make up 6).

Currently I generate all possible kits and while grouping the gear; check to see if the kit has all the attributes before putting it in a collection. This method is rather slow as you can imagine, and I've been really at a loss of how to optimize this via a data structure or otherwise, apart from maybe using a database.

Comment: Are you using the words "ability" and "attribute" interchangeably? If not, what is an attribute?

Comment: yes I apologize I meant ability when I said attribute

Comment: And in the case where the abilities are not completely specified, do you want (a) all possible kits? (b) some possible kits? (c) one randomly-selected possible kit? If it's all possible kits and k is 0, that's going to be a large collection, no matter what algorithm you use. Or am I missing something?

Comment: all kits that contain the abilities specified, k is between 0 and 7 exclusively (1,2,3,4,5,6)

Answer (score 0):

**Invert your problem, by taking the result, and look at how to construct it.**

The algo which follows has a fixed time to pre-compute, and then a minimal time, to compute every kits, depending on how many items in each group.

In each type - say A, B, C, let us group together, items with 2 defined capabilities => then you have 15 distinct groups (6x5/2) in A, 15 in B, 15 in C.

Then you have 3375 possibilities. But only 15 x 6 = 80 goods.

Algorithm:

- 1 group together elements of A, of B, of C with same abilities and put them in a sort of map : element => GA1, ... (see above)
- 2 generate and separate the 15 groups of A, the 15 of B, the 15 of C

like GA1, GA2, ... GA15, GB1, GB2, ... GB15, GC 1, GC2, GC15

- 3 generate compatible GA / GB / GC like a list you will have 80 lists
- 4 then take each of the 80 lists, and replace inside , elements of A, of B and of C

then you have every possible kits.

Comment: sorry I'm not sure I follow, where does that number 5 come from in the calculation?

Comment: not 5, but 15: A, B and C have sub-groups GA1 to GA15, idem with GBxx, GCxx. 15 sub groups = 15 combinations of 2 capabilities.